# Build a Joomla site around/parallel a Zend Framework app

Tags: zend-framework, joomla

My team has a rather large web application that was built with the Zend Framework, which has become mission-critical to our organization in the past year.  It was built as part of an existing ZF corporate web site that no longer meets our needs.

The ZF app has its own users table in a database.  It also uses Zend_Acl, and some database tables, to control access to modules, and to individual records.  The records largely pertain to people in the system.

Thanks to new business needs, we're now faced with building a new public web site in Joomla.  So, we need: (1) to keep running the old system, in some capacity, and (2) a shiny new Joomla site, (3) integration between the two.

-We can't move custody of the users away from our legacy system, because the people those users represent are elemental to the legacy system's purpose.

-We need the usernames and passwords to be the same, and work the same (we have a 60 day reset policy, our usernames aren't fixed values / are a bit convoluted)

-I looked at Zend_Ldap hoping I could expose our users to Joomla that way, but it seems to be just an LDAP client, and I'm not sure implementing an Ldap server in Zend that uses our existing tables is a good use of time.  An extension that replaces Joomla's authentication would probably be wiser.

-Can our ACL control Joomla or should we have two ACLs exist in parallel.

-Do we write SOAP services in the Zend app to expose the data to the extension, or do we just give database credentials to the Joomla extensions directly.

A pretty broad question, I know, but I am only looking for broad answers: how would you tackle this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. The first step sounds like integrating the Auth system across Joomla! and your ZF app from there you can direct link to the ZF App's pages for logged in users. I would recommend the use of [JFusion](http://jfusion.org/) to integrate the Joomla! authorisation process and match the ACL groups across the two systems. You will have to write your own plugin for JFusion but that will be very simple compared to porting your entire app to a Joomla! extension. [JFusion's GitHub repo is here.](https://github.com/jfusion)
2. Given the data provided you will need to run the ZF App as the `master` for authentication and sync user data to Joomla! via your custom plugin.
3. Once you have your plugin doing the authentication you can use JFusion's direct link mode to link to the ZF App as user that login to Joomla! will be automatically logged into the ZF app (and vice versa).